# UIImage trim white areas around circle IOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage

As the title says I have many images which show a circle. The problem is that the image is a square, and I would like to make transparent the white areas around the circle. This is one of the images:

[image]

Unfortunately the white areas are not visible because the background of stack overflow is white. Is there the possibility to remove the four white corners (without removing all white areas as some of the elements in the circle could be white)?

In photoshop I would use the "magic wand" tool, if you know what I mean. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I want to alter the image itself to contain transparent pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the corner radius to half the image width or height (assuming the images are square, of course):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

imageView.layer.cornerRadius  = imageView.bounds.size.width;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

And, if you like an (additional) border:

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
```

Then, reading your comment, to get an image of this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.layer.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The rendered `image` is exactly the size of the layer now.

To prevent pixelation when scaling up, try this:

```
BOOL  opaque = NO;
short scale  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, opaque, scale);
```

or perhaps with another scale.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not what I am looking for. I need to alter the image itself to contain transparent pixels. I had already thought about this

Comment: ok, this code does exactly what I wanted to do, but I have a problem. I want to take the screenshot not only of the imageView but even of the content that there is over it, without adding it as a subview. Furthermore when I enlarge the image it is pixeled

Comment: wow yes it actually does prevent pixelation. The only problem now is that it doesn't include other elements above the buttons